# AccessViolationException before first line of code in empty program with VS2013 and .NET 4.6

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, access-violation, .net-4.6

I recently installed .NET 4.6 on my development system, but I'm still using Visual Studio 2013. Since installing .NET 4.6, I've been getting an AccessViolationException whenever I try to start a program with debugging:

```
at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
at System.AppDomain.nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

This happens even if the program is targeted at .NET 4.5, and even for completely trivial programs. It does not happen when starting a program without the debugger attached, in either debug or release build.

An example of a program that fails:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    }
}
```

What's going on?

Comment: What add-ons did you install to VS?

Comment: I have Resharper installed. I may have some other things - I'll try uninstalling some and see if that helps.

Answer (score 4):

Installing Visual Studio 2013 Update 5 fixed the problem.